# Visual Studio 2010 and 11 beta Web Designer doesnt support CSS Table?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visualdesigner

In visual studio 2010 and 11 beta if you have a table like this one:

```
<div style="display:table">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell">(row 1 cell 1)</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell">(row 1 cell 2)</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell">(row 2 cell 1)</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell">(row 2 cell 2)</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BnAtp/

In the Visual Designer is seen like this: [image]

In the browser is shown correctly: [image]

Anyone knows if it will be supported in the stable version of visual 11? or if there is a patch/plugin/extension/trick that makes it display correctly in the designer (for visual 2010 or 11)?

Comment: You are missing semi-colons after the property values. I wonder if that's your problem?

Comment: @Andrew Barber: The semi-colon isn't necessary in the last declaration. This applies both to inline styles and CSS rules, and I imagine the VS designer should be able to handle it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber As BoltClock says it isnt necessary in the last declaration, even intellisense does it this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end is not supported in Visual Studio 2010 nor 2012...they dont support other CSS3 rules neither (The design view of a page with twitter bootstrap implemented makes you cry)...

Dont know if some great extension for VS could solve this...seems a fat chance...